# android app stop immediately when running on android 11 only without logcat messages

Tags: java, android, logcat, android-anr-dialog

My problem is that my app is working properly on android 10 and below, but when running on android 11 it stops immediately right after launching.

I don't know exactly what is the reason and the logcat doesn't give a clear error message.

Thanks in advance

this my logcat messages

```
    2022-01-27 20:07:08.866 2914-2914/? E/ryEntertainmen: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x40000000
2022-01-27 20:07:08.866 2914-2914/? E/ryEntertainmen: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x40000000
2022-01-27 20:07:08.866 2914-2914/? E/ryEntertainmen: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x40000000
2022-01-27 20:07:09.134 2914-2977/com.dev.everyEntertainment E/ryEntertainmen: Loaded layer handle (3109881255676878641) for layer /my_product/lib64/libcolorx-loader.so
2022-01-27 20:07:09.134 2914-2977/com.dev.everyEntertainment E/ryEntertainmen: Looking for entrypoint ColorX_Check
2022-01-27 20:07:09.134 2914-2977/com.dev.everyEntertainment E/ryEntertainmen: Found ColorX_Check for /my_product/lib64/libcolorx-loader.so
2022-01-27 20:07:09.134 2914-2977/com.dev.everyEntertainment E/ryEntertainmen: Check failed
2022-01-27 20:07:09.246 2914-2914/com.dev.everyEntertainment E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManager: sInstance is null, start a new sInstance
2022-01-27 20:07:09.395 2914-2973/com.dev.everyEntertainment E/ExtensionsLoader: dlopen failed: library "libhwuiextimpl.so" not found
2022-01-27 20:07:23.192 2914-3165/com.dev.everyEntertainment E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
2022-01-27 20:07:23.513 2914-2973/com.dev.everyEntertainment E/OpenGLRenderer: fbcNotifyFrameComplete error: undefined symbol: fbcNotifyFrameComplete
2022-01-27 20:07:23.513 2914-2973/com.dev.everyEntertainment E/OpenGLRenderer: fbcNotifyNoRender error: undefined symbol: fbcNotifyNoRender
2022-01-27 20:07:23.519 2914-2914/com.dev.everyEntertainment E/ANR_LOG: >>> msg's executing time is too long
2022-01-27 20:07:23.519 2914-2914/com.dev.everyEntertainment E/ANR_LOG: Blocked msg = { when=-14s109ms what=0 target=android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler callback=android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver } , cost  = 14109 ms
2022-01-27 20:07:23.519 2914-2914/com.dev.everyEntertainment E/ANR_LOG: >>>Current msg List is:
2022-01-27 20:07:23.519 2914-2914/com.dev.everyEntertainment E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <1> = { when=-1d1h16m2s578ms what=0 target=android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler callback=android.view.ViewRootImpl$$ExternalSyntheticLambda12 }
2022-01-27 20:07:23.519 2914-2914/com.dev.everyEntertainment E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <2> = { when=-14s105ms what=0 target=android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler callback=androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$2 }
2022-01-27 20:07:23.519 2914-2914/com.dev.everyEntertainment E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <3> = { when=-14s101ms barrier=1 }
2022-01-27 20:07:23.519 2914-2914/com.dev.everyEntertainment E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <4> = { when=-13s610ms what=0 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H callback=android.app.ActivityThread$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1 }
2022-01-27 20:07:23.519 2914-2914/com.dev.everyEntertainment E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <5> = { when=-577ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
2022-01-27 20:07:23.519 2914-2914/com.dev.everyEntertainment E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <6> = { when=-529ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
2022-01-27 20:07:23.519 2914-2914/com.dev.everyEntertainment E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <7> = { when=-446ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
2022-01-27 20:07:23.519 2914-2914/com.dev.everyEntertainment E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <8> = { when=-438ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
2022-01-27 20:07:23.519 2914-2914/com.dev.everyEntertainment E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <9> = { when=-423ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
2022-01-27 20:07:23.519 2914-2914/com.dev.everyEntertainment E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <10> = { when=-346ms what=31 target=android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler obj=com.android.internal.os.SomeArgs@85c692a }
2022-01-27 20:07:23.519 2914-2914/com.dev.everyEntertainment E/ANR_LOG: >>>CURRENT MSG DUMP OVER<<<
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem for the error `Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x40000000`.

In my case, it was fixed by setting the `FLAG_IMMUTABLE` or `FLAG_MUTABLE` on all `PendingIntent` I was using. For example:

```
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, Intent(context, MyActivity.class), FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
```

I'm not sure if it was the actual problem, but after fixing that the error was not shown anymore and the app started successfully.

Also I have to say that stacktrace of the error was printed on the Logcat:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.example.myapp: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
    Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
...
```

I hope it helps you.